# Transformar lista en diccionario Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

En el contexto de listas y diccionarios me surge la siguiente duda.
Tengo que transformar la siguiente lista en un diccionario.

```py
lista_recetas = [
  ['HamburguesaCasera', 'Hamburguesa', 'Tomate', 'Pan'], 
  ['PastelDeCarne', ' Carne', 'Papa', 'Cebolla'], 
  ['EnsaladaEspecial', 'Lechuga', 'Espárragos', 'Tomate']
]
```

**para lograr imprimir:**

```py
dic_recetas = {
  'HamburguesaCasera': ['Hamburguesa','Tomate','Pan'], 
  'PastelDeCarne': ['Carne','Papa','Cebolla'], 
  'EnsaladaEspecial': ['Lechuga','Espárragos','Tomate']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si cada lista contiene lo que sería el atributo para la clave del diccionario en la posición 0, entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
lista_recetas = [['HamburguesaCasera', 'Hamburguesa', 'Tomate', 'Pan'], ['PastelDeCarne', ' Carne', 'Papa', 'Cebolla'], ['EnsaladaEspecial', 'Lechuga', 'Espárragos', 'Tomate']]
diccionario_recetas={}
#Un ciclo for para ir recorriendo la lista
for receta in lista_recetas:
   diccionario_recetas.update({receta[0]:receta[1:]})
```

receta[0] contiene el key o clave para asociar con los ingredientes, luego receta[1:], te retornará el resto de atributos que supongo serán los ingredientes.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!! me sirvió.

Comment: @JorgeCastilloMora Si la respuesa de soyunewok te sirvió, puedes aceptarla c: Te recomiendo leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Aunque en mi opinión, eso de "no pongas gracias en los comentarios" es un poco amargo y en lo personal no estoy de acuerdo con ese punto.

Comment: @DanteS. Sí, me falta leer sobre el tema. Somos personas y agradecer es cortesía.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo @JorgeCastilloMora

Answer (score 1):

Una forma muy compacta de hacerlo sería con comprensión de diccionarios, de la siguiente manera:

```
lista_recetas = [
  ['HamburguesaCasera', 'Hamburguesa', 'Tomate', 'Pan'], 
  ['PastelDeCarne', ' Carne', 'Papa', 'Cebolla'], 
  ['EnsaladaEspecial', 'Lechuga', 'Espárragos', 'Tomate']
]

d = {k: args for k, *args in lista_recetas}
```

imprimiendolo te daría lo que buscas:

```
print(d)

{'HamburguesaCasera': ['Hamburguesa', 'Tomate', 'Pan'], 'PastelDeCarne': [' Carne', 'Papa', 'Cebolla'], 'EnsaladaEspecial': ['Lechuga', 'Espárragos', 'Tomate']}
```